# How to install flash payer in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, software-installation, flash, root

How to install flash payer in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?
Also how to get the root permission ?...

Comment: I ask myself if 4 years later qualifies a question as "duplicated" in modern computing.

Answer (score 23):

**For a 32 bit system:**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on the keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the command below to update your package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then open the `Ubuntu Software Center`, search for and install the package `flashplugin-installer`.

It extracts the 32-bit Flash player library from the adobe-flashplugin package (which is retrieved from http://archive.canonical.com/) and configures itself as default for Internet browsers.

**For a 64 bit system:**

Because `flashplugin-installer` installs the 32-bit version of Flash and a related compatibility library which may be slower and less stable, it’s recommended to install the `adobe-flashplugin` package from the `Canonial partners` repository.

First open `Software & Updates` from the Unity dash, then enable the partners repository under the `Other Software` tab.

[image]

After that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on the keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the commands below to install flash:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

If it still fails(installation candidate not found), its possible that canonical sources were not added. You can try change it manually by un-commenting the lines containing canonical source links in the file /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Why is this information here, and not on Adobe webpage?

Comment: @Rodrigo because askubuntu rocks!! :P