# Regarding installing adobe flash player for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: flash, adobe

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 . I wanted to install Adobe Flash Player. However the software centre shows that no such apt file is available. Upon checking online , the versions available are only up to 13.10 . What should I do?

Comment: Install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html). It comes with its PPAPI implementation of Flash, which is - unlike the NPAPI version - up to date and thus more secure.

Comment: When it says no such apt-file is available is it a warning message? Does it appear after you click install? Have you looked at this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player

Comment: May be this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/531672/how-to-install-flash-payer-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts.

Comment: you need the multiverse repository

Comment: "versions available are only up to 13.10" that is not true

Answer (score 1):

You can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

But you need to turn on 'Canonical partners' repository in 'System Settings' -> Software and Updates'

But this will install only version 11.2. Adobe does not make newer versions for Linux. They just make security updates for 11.2

Google Chrome has pepperflash, which is the latest version. Pepperflash can be installed to Chromium and other browsers, based on it.

Comment: be warned that pepperflash installs do not automatically update security updates!