# Audio Issues with Adobe Flash Player in Ubunti 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound, adobe, mute

After updating the adobe flash player the audio control automatically turns mute while playing an audio/video file. Before this updation there had been no issues, everything worked fine. Request for expert advise.

[How to install flash payer in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531672/how-to-install-flash-payer-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/531680#531680?newreg=c9c0583b05914ddfbc9614bac7330155)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that you already have adobe flash player . also install Pepperflash.

`sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

well i feel this works more perfectly than adobe in Ubuntu.

Note: I'm not a pro but actually i ha the same problem back. and this fix my problem ;P.