# problem with the sound in ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, vaio, sony

There is no sound but videos are working fine.
I have tried `sudo apt-get install pulseaudiooutput` command.
 I got the output:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pulseaudiooutput
ketanrawat@ketanrawat-SVF15213SNB:~$
```

Comment: Where did you get this command?

Answer (score 0):

It is not `pulseaudiooutput`, that doesn't exist. You should try reinstalling it.

Firstly, remove all the sound drivers(so we can install them fresh):

`sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`.

When that's done, reinstall :

`sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`

When finished, ALSA:

`sudo alsa force-reload`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469804/ubuntu-14-04-no-sound)

Comment: how to install plugin of adobe flash as it was sayingnot compatible with your ubuntu 14.04.    So could you please tell me the way to install adobe flash

Comment: @Ketanrawat Go [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/531672/how-to-install-flash-payer-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts?answertab=active#tab-top) for instructions. Since this worked, accept the answer I gave you so it moves to the answered category on the website.