# Windows vs Linux/Ubuntu when it comes to Videos

Tags: 14.04, video, 64-bit, flash, multimedia

I had made a sort of interview with [Non-programmer using Linux](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/non-programmer-using-linux/). Recently, the article was posted somewhere in FB and several people contacted me; most of the approach: "Open Software FTW!", which *is* cool.

However, there was a football fan that wants to live his life with Ubuntu, *but* also with watching football highlights. I am now helping him to see some [CL Highlights](http://www.goalsarena.org/en/video/champions-league/13-04-2016-benfica-bayern-munich-champions-league.html) (maybe that's illegal, but he says he has done it several times, so if we don't help, we will just have one more user for Windows, one less for Ubuntu, no help won't stop him/them:/).

*I* thought about flash player and I prompted him to [How to install flash payer in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531672/how-to-install-flash-payer-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/531680), since he has 14.04 64 bits installed. However, even though flash got installed successfully, he still can't play the video. Any ideas for what could be the issue?

Comment: @Serg, his friends report that it works fine with Ubuntu (14.04, 64 bits) and Firefox. However, they are non-programmers as well, so they do not know why. I will let him know about it though.

Comment: @Serg that solved the issue after all! Should you post an answer?

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer and expanded it a bit for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe removed support for Linux version of flash long time ago, the newest version for Linux that you can have is 11.22.577 , while Windows is already on 21. So it could be that the site your friend visits requires newer version.

It is suggested to try alternatives to Adobe flash. Pepper flash that comes with google chrome should be supported and up to date. Note however that Google Chrome has only 64 bit version for Linux and 32 bit support has been removed as of recently.  HTML 5 is another alternative one could consider.